# How to redirect to home page, when user is changed

Tags: asp.net, session, web-applications, cookies

I am in a problem and I hope that you guys will help me out.
I have a web application, in which when I once logged in then if I open the application in a new tab in redirects me to the home page(which shows after login). but when I logout from one tab and login with a different user then my previous tab should be redirected to the home page of current user(if I perform some activity on it)

please help me how do I achieve that..?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Cookies` to map `session` ,It seems you are using some id in url to map it with session

Comment: i login with a user ABC--> ABC HOME PAGE, now i copied the url into a new tab, then i logout. the previous tab remain same. now I login with a different user XYZ in 2nd tab of the explorer--> XYZ HOME PAGE. now i return to the first tab in which the ABC HOME PAGE is open then i click on some link. I want to refresh the page because the logged in user is change from ABC to XYZ

Comment: it should be done automatically if you  click on some link from previous tab it should go to XYZ's page if you have used cookie to manage session'

Comment: how do I find out that a new user is logged in.

Comment: ok tell me, if I create a cookie on login , then logout. then login with a different user will also set that cookie, then how would I know that the cookie is changed. actually i have refresh the page iff a different user login. if i log out then login with the same user then it should not refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

you can use a small trick, place a label in your form and wrap it in timer and updatepanel now set the timer interval to 3000 and in the code behind set the user login and logout some variable and change the label text accordingly let say if 1 for loged 0 for logout so if its 1 nothing happens and if its 0 then redirect the page.

hope it gives you and idea.